# Is there a way to make http requests while looping through an array and returning the array with the request result?

Tags: javascript, arrays

The question might seem silly and unclear because I essentially don't know what approach I should take in order to achieve this, but it will make more sense when I give examples.

So, lets say we have the following array:

```
const arr = [{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}, {key1: '', key2: 'value2'}, {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}]
```

As you can see, the item at index 1 has no value for the `'key1'` key , but I can get this value from an http request.

What I'm ultimately trying to achieve is loop through the array, check if `key1` has a value, if not make an http request to get said value and get a new array where all the indexes have a value for `key1`.

Something like this ( which obviously doesnt work )

```js
const arr = [{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}, {key1: '', key2: 'value2'}, {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}];

arr.map(i => {
  if (!i.key1) {
    const value = getValueFromHttpRequest();
    
    return {
      ...i,
      key1: value
    }
  }
  
  return i;
})
```

So a working example of an array I would get would be

```
[{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}, {key1: 'valueFromHttpRequest', key2: 'value2'}, {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}]
```

I know it sounds confusing, but I appreciate any help I can get with this.

Comment: Do you want to request 1 at a time? All at the same time? Do you care?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Promise.all` to get an array of responses.

```js
const arr = [{key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}, {key1: '', key2: 'value2'}, {key1: 'value1', key2: 'value2'}];

const result = Promise.all(arr.map(async (i) => {
  const value = await sendRequest();
  
  return value;
}));
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're inside an async function already, you can request them 1 at a time using a standard for loop

```
for (const el of arr) {
   if (el.key1) continue; // skip all elements that already have key1
   const response = await requestInfo();
   el.key1 = response.something; // this is what I mean by 'edit the array as you go'
   ...
}
```

Comment: I would like to get the final array when all the requests have finished, if that makes sense.

Comment: Just edit the array as you go, and return it at the end of the function. Are you comfortable with async functions?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by edit the array as you go. Is it possible to give a working example ?

Comment: I've edited my code above. You can edit each object as you're iterating over it.

Comment: Can this be done without mutating the orginail array ? In for example a `map` ?

Comment: @Asa: of course, but could you edit your wisdom to specify your requirements clearly, rather than asking for "just one more thing..." following edits and improvements? This makes it easier to help you, and less frustrating for the people trying to help.

Answer (score 0):

You can loop over the keys and for empty `key1`s you can make an API call and get the value.

```js
const getKey1 = () =>
  new Promise((res) => setTimeout(() => res("value1")), 1000);

const keys = [
  { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" },
  { key1: "", key2: "value2" },
  { key1: "value1", key2: "value2" },
];

async function fillMissingKeys(keys) {
  return Promise.all(
    keys.map(async ({ key1, key2 }) => ({
      key1: !key1 ? await getKey1() : key2,
      key2,
    }))
  );
}

fillMissingKeys(keys).then(console.log);
```